# create a map with value as generic type and ability to do operation in the value after retrieval from the map

Tags: java, generics

There is class Repository as

```
public class Repository<T> {


    public void add(T t){

    }
}
```

Another class RepoHolder defined as

```
public class RepoHolder {


    private Map<String, Repository<?>> repoMap = new HashMap<String, Repository<?>>();

    public Repository<?> getRepo(String type){  
        return repoMap.get(type);
    }


    public void registerRepo(String repoType,Repository<?> repo){
        repoMap.put(repoType, repo);
    }

}
```

I want to perform an operation as :

```
    Repository<String> repo = new Repository<String>();
    holder.registerRepo("mykey", repo);
    Repository<?> repo1 = holder.getRepo("mykey");
    //below doesn't compile
                repo1.add("fdfd");
```

The above code snippet doesn't compile. How can I achieve this use case?

Comment: "The above code snippet doesn't compile" Why? Is it this line: `repo1.add("fdfd");`? Or something else?

Comment: @AndyTurner yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines:

```
Repository<?> repo1 = holder.getRepo("mykey");
repo1.add("fdfd");
```

are obviously not type correct: you're trying to put a `String` into something that you don't know what the type of the parameter should be. It *could* be a `Repository<String>`, but it could alternatively be a `Repository<Integer>` (or a `Repository<AnythingElse>`).

The "obvious" fix here is to make `getRepo` generic:

```
public <T> Repository<T> getRepo(String type){  
    return (Repository<T>) repoMap.get(type);
}
```

because then you could write:

```
Repository<String> repo1 = holder.getRepo("mykey");
repo1.add("fdfd");
```

but *please* don't, because you could equally write

```
Repository<Integer> repo1 = holder.getRepo("mykey");
repo1.add(123);
```

and it would fail at runtime.

You need some means of associating the type with the repo.

For example, you could pass in an additional parameter to `getRepo`:

```
public <T> Repository<T> getRepo(String type, Class<T> clazz)
```

and then add logic inside that method to ensure that the repository identified by `type` actually is an instance of "`Repository<clazz>`".

For example, you could change the map in the repository holder class to also take into account the class:

```
private Map<Class<?>, Map<String, Repository<?>>> repoMap = new HashMap<>();
```

i.e. you can have multiple repositories with the same string key, because they are identified by a `(Class, String)` pair.

Alternatively, you can have typed *keys*:

```
interface RepositoryKey<T> {
  // ...
}
```

and when you *put* an element into the holder, you get a typed key:

```
public <T> RepositoryKey<T> registerRepo(String repoType,Repository<T> repo){
    RepositoryKey<T> key = ...
    repoMap.put(key, repo);
    return key;
}
```

Now you can use the key to retrieve it type-safely:

```
Repository<String> repo = new Repository<String>();
RepositoryKey<String> key = holder.registerRepo("mykey", repo);

Repository<String> repo1 = holder.getRepo(key);
repo1.add("fdfd");
```

---

Note that there is an item in *Effective Java* about this: "Consider typesafe heterogeneous containers". It's Item 29 in the 2nd Ed. You should read that for a lot more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
Map<String, Repository<?>> repoMap = new HashMap<String, Repository<?>>();
```

you should have the type of the repo as the key

```
Map<Class<T>, Repository<T>> repoMap = new HashMap<Class<T>, Repository<T>>();
```

That way you could retain the type info and use it like

```
Repository<String> repo1 = holder.getRepo(String.class);
            repo1.add("fdfd");
```